# Fetch altered data after page is updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

When update button is submitted a function `edit_page()`  is called. This function alter the database table row with new data entered.
This works fine table altered correctly entries are ok.
But problem is that when update button is submitted 
1. Entries is database inserted or altered correctly.
2. But when page reloads content of this updated page remains as it is as previous or like before updation on front end or just after submission.

My code:

```
<?php

function edit_page()
{
add_cat();
global $page_id; 
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page_action']) && ($_GET['page_action'] == 'edit'))
    {
    $page_id = $_GET['post'];
    } 
?>
<?php
$page_id = $_GET['post'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = '$page_id'"); //execute the SQL query and return records
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$page_title = $row['page_title'];
$page_content = $row['page_content']; 
?>
<form  method="post" action="" name="edit_page" class="edit_page">
<h4>Page Title:</h4> <input type="text" name="title" class="title" placeholder="Add title of the Page" required value="<?php echo  $page_title;?>"/><br/>
<h4>Page Content:</h4><br/> 
<textarea cols="80" id="content" name="content" rows="10"><?php echo $page_content;?></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="page_edits" value="yes" />   
<input type="submit" name="edit_page"  class="button" value="Update"/>

<?php
save_edits(); }

function save_edits()
    {
if (isset($_POST['edit_page']) && $_POST['page_edits'])
    {
    $page_id = $_GET['post'];
    $page_id = $_GET['post'];
    $page_title = $_POST['title'];
    $page_content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i');
    $query = "UPDATE pages SET page_title='$page_title', page_content='$page_content', date_gmt='$date' WHERE page_id = '$page_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to create Page: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
<div class="right_sidebar">
<?php edit_page();?></div>
```

Finally, my mean is that i just want functionality like wordpress in which when update button is clicked just after that we see updated data.

Comment: You should save the changes before loading the page content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing PHP the procedural way here. That means the statements are executed one after another so the problem lies in the way you place your statements.

In your code, you are displaying the form first and only then updating it, so that's why the previous values get fetched although update is happening only later.

**Solution:** The function `save_edits()` and its call should come first followed by `edit_page().`

Another important thing in terms of security, you are directly inserting the value you get from the address bar. Right now the way it is, someone can drop your whole table by writing in a [piece of code](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html#noro). You could use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent it (although not totally) or better yet:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Lastly, you are not closing your `<form>` tag.

Comment: ok im trying your code<form> tag is closed in my code actually here i pasted only required code other i deleted so it may typo error here

Comment: i never thinked like you your statement works thanks @I Can Has Kittenz and this is my admin panel not front end. Later i m looking for implementing your other suggestions.