# How to re-populate a dynamically generated form select field after submit?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, select

So, I have form as shown in the code snippet below.

tl;dr - form has a select field that gets its options dynamically from database table with a distinct sql query and on submit inserts new row into the table, then returns to the form.

Issue - after submit and insert, the drop down select field doesn't show the newest added option even though the row was added to the table. I have to manually refresh the page to get the drop down to have the newest option available.

Please help me with this issue as I do not want to load this page on each time new data item is added.

How can I force the form to re-populate the select field after each successful submit?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<?php 
 $lsql = 'SELECT distinct(location) FROM some_table';
 $result = mysql_query($lsql);
?>
 <select class="field" name="locations" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

 <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 $key = str_replace(',', '', $row['location']);
 $key = str_replace(' ', '', $key);
 $loc = $row['location'];
 $locations[$key] = $loc;
 echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$loc.'</option>';
 }
 ?>
 <option value="other">Other</option>
 </select>
 <div id="otherloc"></div>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['newjob'])) {
// getting form data
$location = $_POST['location'];
$other = $_POST['other'];
$jlocation = ($locations[$jlocation])? $locations[$jlocation] : $jother;

// Then, get all the fields data and insert into a database table

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}
?>
```

The showfield() is a javascript function that adds an input text field in the 'otherloc' div when the 'Other' option is selected in the dropdown. The insert changes the same table, so I need to get fresh distinct(locations) every time the form loads anew.

Comment: hmmm i think this already happens by doing `header('Location:...` after inserting. Does your `header('...` work? Another way is to do the insert before the select but the header stuff is better because of various reasons.

Comment: Uuuups header could not work because of doing some outputs before sending header. Do the `if (isset($_POST['newjob'])) { ...` before your outputs.

Comment: @steven - the header works fine, i have tried various pages in the directory structure and it redirects correctly.

Comment: I put the isset part up top as @nothing reminded me and it works fine now. Thanks guys. I knew there is a reason why I had always done so but for whatever reason, I put it down below this once and couldn't see the obvious flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your queries like this or revert the parts like 

    `<?php if (isset($_POST['newjob'])) { } ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">  </form>`

 I think it will help you

Comment: here is the something like urs asked by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669287/fetch-altered-data-after-page-is-updated

Comment: It works but I put that part right up top after the session_start() . I prefer it that way too as I don't like to put it somewhere within the body. It messes with formatting and makes scrolling to other parts of the html annoying. Thanks though.

Comment: If i am clear then you can put if statement before form where you want to display errors . And you can put this anywher in body before the form it will not harm you anymore or if you put in header then it may distract your design

Answer (score 1):

Check your error logs to see if everything is ok. I suspect that `header(...)` is not working. Also you might consider inserting location to database before you create the select.

Comment: yes you are right. He did some outputs before sending headers.